# How to include a jar without its subjar

Tags: java, spring-boot, algorithm, maven, struts

I have a struts project. It has many jars in its `APP-INF/lib` directory and the packaged ear size is huge. I also have another spring boot project and it has one utility class.

My target is to use that utility from the struts project.

The problem here is, if I include this spring-boot jar in the `pom.xml`, it includes the spring boot jar with all its dependency which are already present in the struts project. This makes the ear more huge. The jars are copied twice in a way. Basically the project becomes like this:

```
struts-project
--APP-INF/libs/
----**.jar (many jars)
----spring-boot-project.jar
--------BOOT-CONF/libs/
-------------**.jar (again many jars, most of them already in one level above directory)
```

My end goal is to use the utility, for which I have 2 ways (what I have in mind, more ways possible)

1. Include the spring boot jar, but find a way to reduce packaged ear size.
2. Create a rest api in the spirng boot project just to use the jar. But if the service is down anyhow, it will have huge impact on main application - so don't want to use this way also.

Please suggest more ways to achieve my end goal. Or any improvement/suggestion in the above approaches.

Comment: Extract the utility.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use utility / commons classes in many project you should create separate project for utility.

Utility project should  not use any dependency or very little in other case you should redesign it.

Comment: The problem is, the utility was never created with the intention that it will be reused. After 4 years, we need it now.

Comment: So it is looks like time to extract to have possibility to reuse.